# Change Button position

Tags: android

I have a button in an AbsoluteLayout and I want to change the X and Y position on screen
programmatically.

How do i it?

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated, and it is not recommended for use in modern Android applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you you need to find or add button on view.

And after that you need to set AbsoluteLayout like

```
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height, x, y))
```